# Is there a way to get RestSharp to automatically use the system proxy in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: .net-core, restsharp, asp.net-core-3.1

Is there a way to get RestSharp to automatically use the system proxy in .NET Core 3.1?  I've found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47675172/229587) implying this should work but for me it doesn't.  I have to explicitly define the proxy with the code below or RestSharp doesn't use the proxy (e.g. Fiddler).  Am I doing something wrong or has there been a regression in RestSharps behaviour?

```
        if (useFiddlerProxy)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            var proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            _client.Proxy = proxy;
        }
```

**EDIT:** It looks like I'm not the only one struggling with this: [Default Proxy in .NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740567/default-proxy-in-net-core-3-1)

Comment: From [github issue](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1043#issuecomment-355776442): "Referring to #1061

.NET Core will not support system proxy. Full framework does."