# how to set default proxy with .NET core 3.1 for HTTP client for any request?

Tags: asp.net-core, proxy, reverse-proxy, interfax

I am using interfax.api dll to send faxes to users. how I can add proxy server configurations to send the fax to users.
actually I want to enable proxy server settings in .net core. what is best way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the issue not seems to be with interfax api. this can be solved with adding proxy uri to your .net core project like that

```
HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy("http://199.169.6.177:5589/", true);
```

in your startup class ConfigureServices method